# How can I set a value of dictionary to class method in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to set my class variable as dictionary, and one of the value of that should be a method of this class in initialize time. How can I do that?

I want to do like this.

```
class A:
    myvar = {
        'key1': this.my_method,
        'key2': 'value2',
        ...
    }

    def my_method(self):
        pass
```

Actually, this.my_method in dictionary doesn't work.

Comment: `my_method` is an instance method, it would need an instance to function. Are you sure the method shouldn't be a class method too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value in `__init__`

```py
   def __init__(self):
       self.internal_dictionary[key] = fn()
```

If `fn()` is expensive to compute, will be accessed by threads etc., you could set the key value to be `None` or another sentinel, and guard it

```py
with self.Lock():  # guard against simultaneous thread access
    if self.internal_dictionary.get(key) is None:  # only compute value once
        self.internal_dictionary[key] = fn()
```

Comment: `myvar` is a class attribute - should it be `A.myvar['key1'] = ...`?

Comment: Possibly, however, one should almost-always use `self` when referring to class properties/attributes, likely noted with a comment about its being special. The value will be available in all instances of the class. A technical reason to do this would be making it clearer what happens when inheriting from `A` and defining a new attribute with the same name.